# How to solve the scaling issue in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, text, scale

I have a screen where Im using flutter_screenutil package. When page opens Text value scales per a second. How to solve this problem. I also tried layoutbuilder but doesnt help.

````
Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      appBar: InfoAppbar(
        onTap: () => showLanguageModal(context),
        languageCode: _languageCode,
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
          valueListenable: _pageIndex,
          builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
            return Padding(
              padding: REdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal:Dimens.pagePadding),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'GoogleFonts.poppins',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 32.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: AppColors.textColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        )
          ;
      }),
    )
    ```
P.S : if someone has the same problem, GoogleFonts has scaling behavior, I removed that and now everything works fine
````

Comment: can you add the minimum reproducible code? Looking at the code above, its just a normal text widget

Answer (score 0):

you can add **ScreenUtil.init(context)** inside  Widget build(BuildContext context) , follow below code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Initialize flutter_screenutil
    ScreenUtil.init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      key: globalKey,
      appBar: InfoAppbar(
        onTap: () => showLanguageModal(context),
        languageCode: _languageCode,
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context,BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
          valueListenable: _pageIndex,
          builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? child) {
            return Padding(
              padding: REdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal:Dimens.pagePadding),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'GoogleFonts.poppins',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 32.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: AppColors.textColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        )
          ;
      }),
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide me error screenshot or full code

Comment: there is not any error, just my text scales a second when screen is opening. After a second it stops moving

Comment: can you provide screenshot

Comment: I solved the problem, it was cause of GoogleFonts.poppins. I removed and everything works okay